# Make a countdown timer display a modal window bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, modal-dialog, countdown

I have another issue. This time I want to make that when a countdown timer reaches 0 it triggers or display a modal window to show up.

I have both the codes for the modal and the countdown timer, but I dunno how exactly make it so it calls for the modal.

I've tried several suggestions I've read but none works or it just screws the code.

Many thanks in advance.

```js
var seconds = 300; //**change 120 for any number you want, it's the seconds **//
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Last chance!";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
 
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```html
<!-- Modal start-->
<div class="modal fade" id="ventanamdl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content"> <!-- to create more modals copy-paste from the div class "modal fade" until here, you can customize moda-content with css-->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1>This is your last chance!</h1>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                        
            <p>Your spot can't be reserved any longer! Click the button to join now!
            <br>
            <button id="btnjoin" type="submit" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">Join!</button>
            </p>   
              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            This is your last chance!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- Modal end-->
    

<div id="bottomdiv">
  <p class="mytext2">Over 87 people have claimed their spot. Get yours before time runs out! <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$('#ventanamdl').modal('show');
```

For your purpose

```
var seconds = 300; //**change 120 for any number you want, it's the seconds **//
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Last chance!";
        $('#ventanamdl').modal('show');
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

//now your setInterval call is ok
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Your setInterval call was not ok.

Make sure your bootstrap CSS and JS and jQuery are properly loaded.

Comment: I tried this one and set the timer to 10 seconds to test, however after those 10 seconds have passed the modal isn't showing up. But thank you for your help!

It could be also something in my modal html in which I'd have to check tomorrow since im tired.

Comment: You can check now. I have edited the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: No, it isnt working yet. I will have to check the code properly tomorrow. It's a bad idea to code when you're sleepy haha.

Comment: Ok. Let me know.

Comment: Alright. I checked again and it's not working. When the when the timer reaches 0 and 'Last chance!' pops up the modal aint appearing. I'll try looking into the CSS code as well to see if there's something wrong.

Comment: Make sure your  bootstrap CSS and JS and jQuery are properly loaded.

Comment: That was it! there was an error when I was adding de bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js! Now it's completely working!! Many thanks!